# Why Is There a Black Bar on Top of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I installed Google Chrome on Windows 8. When run from the Desktop, it runs as expected. However, when I run it from the Start screen, where all the apps are laid out in tile/mosaic format, there is a black bar at the top of the screen. When I click on it, the browser window shrinks to about 1/5 of its regular size, and I can drag it around horizontally (but not vertically). What is going on?

[image]

And when I click and drag the black bar...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 has certain guidelines for the Modern Apps - one such being the absence of the Title bar & the minimize/maximize/close buttons.

Google Chrome looks different when opened from Start Screen than when opened from the Desktop if it is set as the default browser.

Windows 8 sets a default program for each service - For instance, one for the browser, one for opening PDF files, one for opening photos and one for watching videos. If you have set IE as your default browser, you would see Google Chrome opening in the same familiar way, irrespective of how you opened it (and you wouldn't see the black bar). However if you set Google Chrome as the default browser, opening from the Start Screen leads to Windows 8 recognizing it as a Modern UI App (since its the "default" program for browsing) and requires it to be opened in the Modern-UI mode - striping off its Title bar & making it look different (and hence the black bar). Opening it from Desktop poses no such restrictions and hence you see the familiar Google Chrome UI.

About dragging it - you can drag it down to close the browser and if your screen resolution supports it, you can drag it left or right to pan it on the side.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be part of "Microsoft Design Language" app to me.

[image]

Comment: What about being able to drag it horizontally, but not vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the Modern UI app version of Chrome.
[Modern UI apps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/apps) always run in full screen.